# Get branch name of not the current one gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr

I have a job on gitlab-ci that runs once I creat a new branch (release/0.0.0), this job build and push a docker image into aws ECR. And I used the name of the branch as a tag of the image as shown below.

```
script:
    - docker build -t back:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
     - docker tag back:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME aws_ecr_url/back:$$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
     - docker push aws_ecr_url/back:$$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

Another job on the branch master that runs when I push a tag, this job is for pulling the image pushed from the release branch.

```
script:
    - docker pull aws_ecr_yrl/back:$ ??
```

THE PROBLEM I don't know what to put in the place of "??" to have the image created by the job in the release.

I used  `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~/regex/` but it didn't work. and I didn't find any predifined variable to get another branch name.

Any solution to get this done ?

Comment: Is the branch name you're trying to find always the same branch? One that was just merged into master? Something else?

Comment: yes the merge will be always from the release, but it's name will changed everytime

Comment: If this pipeline comes from a merge request, you can get the source branch (the branch that will be merged into the target) with one of the predefined variables `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`. That will be null however if the pipeline runs and it isn't from a merge request. All the predefined variables can be found in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), and the merge request specific ones are about halfway down [that page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines)

Comment: I have found a solution for it if u are intrested

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

If anyone is looking for a solution of this I have used the cache to solve it.

```
job_in_release:
cache:
 key: tag
 paths:
  - cache
 policy: push
 
script:
 - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME > cache/tag/file.txt'

job_in_master
 cache:
 key: tag
 paths:
  - cache
 policy: pull

 script:
  - su -
  - export TAG=$(cat cache/tag/file.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use artifacts instead cache for different job execution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).